# Multithreaded summation of arrays in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, numpy

I have two arrays of size `n1 X n2` and I want them to be added together in parallel. I have an `openMP` enabled build of `Python`, but when I set `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` inside of my `bash` shell before execution, I don't see my code being multithreaded. Is it possible to perform `arr = arr + tarr` in a mulithreaded way?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np

n1 = 20000
n2 = 20000

arr = np.random.random_sample((n1,n2))

for i in range(10):
    tarr = np.random.random_sample((n1,n2))
    arr = arr+tarr
```

Comment: Your title is about 'vectorized', but the text is about 'threading'.  Those are different issues.

Comment: Was `numpy` and/or its libraries (BLAS etc) built with `openMP`?

Comment: I don't think simple array addition is done with BLAS. Do operations like dot product or equation solving get multithreaded?

Comment: Yes, you are right about vectorization and threading. I have two versions - one with AVX specific compilation and one without. The AVX compilation does not get speed up, nor does is use multiple threads so I said both but didn't specify the difference. Apologies.

Comment: Yes, the version I am using was compiled with Intel MKL.

Comment: Yes, dot products and singular value decompositions are multithreaded AND vectorized (super linear speed up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BLAS linkage would only be only relevant for linear algebra operations (matrix products, solving linear systems etc.). numpy itself does not multithread basic elementwise arithmetic operations on arrays (such as addition, non-matrix multiplication, exponentiation etc.).

One of the simplest options for multithreading that calculation would be to use [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import numexpr as ne

In [3]: n1, n2 = 5000, 5000

In [4]: x = np.random.randn(n1, n2)

In [5]: %%timeit y = np.random.randn(n1, n2)
   ...: x + y
   ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 245 ms per loop

In [6]: %%timeit y = np.random.randn(n1, n2)
   ...: ne.evaluate('x + y')
   ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 83.6 ms per loop
```